# I can't choose image in Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry

I created Container Registry, Web App for Containers and published image from Visual Studio but I don't see any image on the list? Why?[image]

[image]

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I see that there is a refreshed symbol in the screenshot you provided. When you select the Registry server, there will be a process to read the registry and the process will cost a little time. So you need to wait a while.

And on my site, the Azure Container Registry works fine for the Web App for Container, you can see it here:

[image]

If any more question, you can give me the message.